# how to access ansible list when re-using variable name

Tags: list, variables, ansible

I have two simple lists:

```yaml
developer:
  - user_1
  - user_2

admin:
  - user_3
  - user_4
```

The value of the variable *team* will be either "developer" or "admin". I want to use it to access the lists mentioned above. The below task doesn't work like I was hoping:

```yaml
   - name: print list
     debug:
       msg: "{{ item }}"
     loop: "{{ team }}"
```

Instead of printing the list, I'm getting this error:

> msg: 'Invalid data passed to ''loop'', it requires a list, got this instead: developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the lookup plugin *vars*. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all

  vars:

    developer:
      - user_1
      - user_2

    admin:
      - user_3
      - user_4

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ lookup('vars', team) }}"
```

gives abridged

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -l host_1 -e team=admin pb.yml

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host_1] => (item=user_3) => 
  msg: user_3
ok: [host_1] => (item=user_4) => 
  msg: user_4
  ...
```